# jsp vulnerability detection

Tags: jsp, security, xss

i have got some jsp code with xss vulnerabilities. I unfortunatelly cannot see them... Could you please help to localize them?

```
<%
String user = request.getParameter("user");
String title = request.getParameter("title");
String text = request.getParameter("text");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT user FROM messages WHERE title=’"+title+"’");
out.println("The title of the message is "+ title + "."); if(rs.hasNext()) {
out.println("A message with this title has already been created by " + row.getString("user") + ".");
}
else {
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO messages (title,user,text) VALUES (’"+title+"’,’"+user+"’,’"+text+"’);
out.println("The message has been created.");
} %>
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: I do not see XSS issues in your code, but **A LOT** of [SQL Injection](http://www.royabubakar.com/blog/2014/01/19/sql-injection-in-java-web-application/) issues. **Never ever** construct SQL queries by string concatenation, always use [Prepares Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: Actually, now I see the XSS problem in the `out.println("The title of the message is "+ title + ".");` statement - guess, what happens, if I post `<script>alert("Hello, world!");</script>` as `title`. And the content of the script can be much more harmful than just displaying an alert.

Comment: row.getString("user") also should be escaped using commons-lang's StringEscapeUtils for example